# How can I show the Database Host name I am connected in a PHP Query?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way that I can show the details of the database I am connected at via mysql query?

I have tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
function checkConnection() {
    //$query = mysql_ping();
    $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT variable_value INTO @local_hostname
        FROM information_schema.global_variables
        WHERE variable_name = 'hostname'
    ");
    if ($query) {
        return $query;
    } else {
        return "Database DISCONNECTED";
    }
}
```

Comment: Define *"it doesn't work"*.

Comment: but don't you know the host already?... How did you get connected without it?

Comment: how did you establish the connection? PDO, any DBAL, ... If you have a connection object (and you obviously have), there should be something inside.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: im trying to retrieve the hostname of the database i am connected @NaijaProgrammer

Comment: @Fred-ii- it doesnt return the hostname

Comment: @JulioSoares yes i know, i just want to show it for experiment. i want to play with the code

Comment: seems to be a variable scope issue

Comment: try your code without the custom `checkConnection()` function. If it works, then again... as I said, it's a variable scope issue.

Comment: Do you need this? `show variables WHERE Variable_name like '%host%';`

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer I have 5 near identical projects and I occassionally upload a db config file to the wrong project since all the files in all the folders are identical among the 5. Nothing breaks because all 5 projects database structures are identical. The contents of all tables in all 5 projects are near identical because they regularly import data from a common source.

So I'm trying to get the database in use to always display in my administration area for my sanity. The connection happens in a function that doesn't return anything so I can't capture the db name in a global var to show.